# Помогите точно расставить запятые в предложениях

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

> 1. Я зашел в дом и, не увидев там никого, я пошел дальше.
> 2. Зайдя в дом и не увидев там никого, я пошел дальше.

Answer (score 1):

> Запятые правильно расставлены в этих примерах или нет?

ПРАВИЛЬНО.

**P.S.**

В первом примере -- лишнее "я" (перед "пошёл дальше").

Answer (score 1):

Если в первом предложении ничего не менять,как предложил Слава,перед И тоже нужна запятая, т.к. это сложносочинённое предложение

1) Я зашел в дом, и, не увидев там никого, я пошел дальше.